# Concerns between IntelliJ and Grails/Gradle

Tags: tomcat, grails, intellij-idea

I am using Grails 3.0.5 (which uses gradle 2.6). My environment is IntelliJ 14. My JVM is Java 1.8 oracle (in JAVA_HOME) and I am trying to deploy it on tomcat 8.0.26.

Assume the project is fresh as created by `grails start-app`. When I deploy it in tomcat8 and I run the very first request, I get an exception like this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

But there's an exception occurring before: the same, not being able to find /index.

The UrlMappings file is like this:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

And such view files exist (even tried adding explicitly .gsp extension to these UrlMappings entries):

[image]

My deployment is against a local tomcat8 instance, either with a war or exploded deploy.

But I get the mentioned exception when I try to open an URL (and the view files are present in WEB-INF/classes).

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at [this issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/605)?

Comment: As I read ¿does it mean I cannot use it on tomcat8 since tomcats do not support spring boot?